# How to pass a Credental asset to New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

I retrieved an asset using:

```
$creds = Get-AzureRmAutomationCredential `
-AutomationAccountName "my-account" `
-ResourceGroupName "test" `
-Name "cred1"
```

Now I want to pass the username and password to `New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport` but `$cred.Password` returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `$creds.GetType().FullName`?  Is it a PSCredential? String? etc.

Comment: It's a `CredentialInfo` object. I created this Credential in the Automation Account via the Portal. I thought I could import it to avoid hardcoding the password in my automation script.

Comment: Does it have members? What do you get back from `$creds | Get-Member`